# junit - Expected and actual values are same but the test result is failure

Tags: java, junit

Expected and actual values are same but the test result is failure in JUnit test. I don't know why this happens. Codes and result image are attached. One more weird thing is that there are error marks in the packages even though the source codes do not have any errors. An image about this is also attached). I guess two things are related each other. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.If you need more information, please ask me.

```
package tests;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import net.n3.nanoxml.*;

public class NanoSetAttr3_wy_v1Tests extends TestCase {

    public void test0() throws Exception {
        //setattr3.out
        String result;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer;

        byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(byteBuffer));
        try{
            SetAttr3_wy_v1.main(new String[] {});
        }catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        result = new String(byteBuffer.toByteArray());
        assertEquals(result, "<FOO Weight=\"80\"/>");
    }

}
```

[image: junit compares results]
[image: package error marks]

Comment: It looks like the "expected" result has a newline that isn't present in "actual".

Comment: Oh, thanks! That was the reason. What about the error marks in the packages?

Comment: Could be errors cached by the IDE.  Try cleaning and building the package and see if that removes the errors.

Comment: @Junghyun It's polite to accept the answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look closely at the Expected and Actual windows, you'll see that Expected has two lines and Actual has one.  This means that the Expected output has a newline but the Actual output does not.

Regarding the error marks, open up Problems window for details (if you're not using Eclipse, there should be something similar).